# How to provide password for wget in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, wget

I'm exploring a custom software package written in Python. This package contains a function that fetch files from a remote repository. When I use the function on a IPython shell(or interpreter), the terminal asks for the password for the repository, and I can successfully download the files by typing the correct password. However, when I use the function within a jupyter notebook, then the function is executed without any password input and thus fails. Instead, in the terminal where I launched the jupyter notebook I see a message "password for (username):". Of course, typing the password here after the function has failed does not affect the jupyter notebook

I could I provide password for wget within a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a bypassing method using http.server.

1. Open your notebook.
2. Run this command in a cell.(you can change the port '8888' as your own.)

```py
!python3 -m http.server 8888 --directory /
```

3. Now you can use wget without password or token.

```sh
wget server_url:8888/path/to/file
```